# Rich Text Area Field in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

For one of the requirements I need to send email from a visualforce page. Email body is expected to be entered in rich text area input(similar to salesforce object rich text area fields). Due to some limitation I can not bind some richtextarea field on user interface to show an editor.

Is it possible to achieve salesforce richtextarea element look without field binding. 
If not, What would be other options to display same considering I can not go for some paid/licensed editor for same.

Comment: try creditor. SF also use this tool internally and its free as well.

Comment: Thank you Tushar. Any web link/ references for creditor ?

Comment: try the [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use below tag to display richtext area in visualforce page.

```
<apex:inputtextarea label="RichText"  richtext="true" value="{!body}" 
     id="Body" cols="100" rows="15"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to like this :

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.RichText__c}"/>
```

Comment: OP asking for the rich text

Comment: Why the downvote? Using an `apex:inputField` with a Rich Text field seems like a valid workaround for me.